# Example environment?

Tags: environments, examples

I was wondering if there is any formal environment for specifying 'examples' through out the text. If not, which environments do you recommend?

Comment: What kind of examples?

Comment: @N.N. A simple one which gives some indentation and enables a logical recognition of the example, through \label{example1} and \ref{example1}.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could use the [`amsthm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package. As per their recommendations, which is what most people use, you should define the environment as

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
```

and than use is as

```
\begin{exmp}
This is the example.
\end{exmp}
```

Note however, that the above definition will give the examples its own counter. If you already have theorems and definitions using the `thm`-counter, you might want to consider using

```
\newtheorem[thm]{exmp}
```

since it can be very confusing for the reader if you have Theorem 3, Lemma 3, Definition 3 and Example 3 on different pages.

Comment: Thank you @Carsten. but loading amsthm errs with "Command \proof already defined." I am using Springer llncs.cls. Any advice?

Comment: @Md Oliya In that case you do not need the `amsthm` package. `llncs` provides this feature itself. According to section 8 of its documentation you should simply use `\begin{example} <text> \end{example}`. For using the same counter for Theorems, Definitions etc load the class with the option `envcountsame`.

Comment: Thanx @Carsten. the amsthm package works great. just a question: the counters are like section_number.counter (e.g III.1). how can i use a simple counter? i.e. no section numbers

Comment: @Md Oliya use `\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}` without the `[section]`

Comment: ---------Great!

Comment: how do i remove the damn counter. So frustrating. \begin{exmp*} don't work

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf use `\newtheorem*{exmp}{Example}`

Answer (score 17):

## Updated Answer *2016-03-04*

Here is an alternative using `tcolorbox`. This solution is robust in that it can handle many situations: one page, partial page spans, and multiple page spans. I wrapped everything in a `\NewDocumentEnvironment` macro from `xparse` because it makes it easy to recognize what the input should be.

### Caveat for those using XeLaTeX and `listings` 2016-07-05

*Due to an unknown problem (see [Why is text turning white (possible scope leak?) after page break and listings + tcolorbox + xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308672/why-is-text-turning-white-possible-scope-leak-after-page-break-and-listings)), you should reapply the color "black" explicitly after each "testexample" environment to ensure that your text is visible as expected under all page break conditions.* **Fix is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308854/13552**

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{testexample}{\color{black}} % Bugfix for unknown culprit. When tcolorbox wraps listings compiled with xelatex, subsequential text turns white https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308672/why-is-text-turning-white-possible-scope-leak-after-page-break-and-listings
```

### Example Syntax

```
\begin{testexample}[<optional title>]
<content of example>
\end{testexample}
```

### Code

If desired, examples can be numbered by replacing the line

> `title={\exampletext: #1},% use \thetcbcounter to access the testexample counter text`

with

> `title={\exampletext\ \thetcbcounter: #1},% use \thetcbcounter to access the testexample counter text`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{testexample}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\exampletext{Example} % If English

\NewDocumentEnvironment{testexample}{ O{} }
{
\colorlet{colexam}{red!55!black} % Global example color
\newtcolorbox[use counter=testexample]{testexamplebox}{%
    % Example Frame Start
    empty,% Empty previously set parameters
    title={\exampletext: #1},% use \thetcbcounter to access the testexample counter text
    % Attaching a box requires an overlay
    attach boxed title to top left,
       % Ensures proper line breaking in longer titles
       minipage boxed title,
    % (boxed title style requires an overlay)
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay={}},
    coltitle=colexam,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
       before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt, % Use instead of parbox=true. This ensures parskip is inherited by box.
    % Handles box when it exists on one page only
    overlay unbroken={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: first page
    overlay first={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: middle page
    overlay middle={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: last page
    overlay last={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
    }
\begin{testexamplebox}}
{\end{testexamplebox}\endlist}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{testexample}[Latin Text]
\lipsum[2]
\end{testexample}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{testexample}
\lipsum[2]
\end{testexample}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

## Adding figures

You probably don't want a float figure inside of this example environment, because it is a box itself.

I would probably add the `caption` package and implement it like this:

```
\begin{testexample}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=!,height=2in]{mountain}
\captionof{figure}{Wildspitze 3,770 m (12,370 ft)}
\end{testexample}
```

### Output

[image]

---

## Old Answer

Here is an alternative using `mdframed` and `xparse` (`xparse` is not absolutely necessary, but I adopted it as my main syntax for defining commands and environments due to its flexibility)

## Input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mdframed} % Add easy frames to paragraphs
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse} % Add support for \NewDocumentEnvironment
\definecolor{graylight}{cmyk}{.30,0,0,.67} % define color using xcolor syntax

\newmdenv[ % Define mdframe settings and store as leftrule
  linecolor=graylight,
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  rightline=false,
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep
]{leftrule}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{example}{O{\textbf{Example:}}} % Define example environment
{\begin{leftrule}\noindent\textcolor{graylight}{#1}\par}
{\end{leftrule}}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\begin{example}[Example]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

(`fontspec` used because I compile with XeLaTeX)

Comment: Any idea why the left line will not show up for me?  I tried inserting `leftline=true`, to no avail.  However, but setting `rightline=true` in the setting above, I can get the line on the right to show up.  (The same is true for the other two lines.)

Comment: @Shredderroy I am not sure, but I can tell you that I have since switched to `tcolorbox`, because I found `mdframed` not able to properly handle multipage spanning. Also, I know `TikZ`, so `tcolorbox` was a logical alternative and not a difficult jump to make. I updated my answer. Maybe this alternative will work for you.

Comment: @macmadness86 this looks great. Is it possible to create a version where it is possible to use a float environment like `figure` in the example?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working with dropping the `figure` environment and using `\captionof{figure}{Title}` instead.

Comment: @krtek I was just going to say that. See my update.

Comment: Thanks. To get the margins right from the following text to the caption I put the complete figure code between `\begingroup` and `endgroup`

Comment: is possible add the number at the example and use the \ref{} to make a referimento to it?

Comment: For the case of numbered examples, I tried adding a label:
\begin{testexample}[Latin Text]
label{Example1}
\lipsum[2]
\end{testexample}

and then refering to it with \ref{Example1}, but that doesn't work. Any idea how to get that to work? I also tried the solution given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93856/using-cleveref-with-newenvironment

Answer (score 10):

You can make a simple example environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{examplecounter}
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{quote}%
    \refstepcounter{examplecounter}%
  \textbf{Example \arabic{examplecounter}}%
  \quad
}{%
\end{quote}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}\label{ex:simple}
  A simple example environment

  \lipsum[1]
\end{example}

Some text: \lipsum[4]

\begin{example}\label{ex:another}
  Another example
\end{example}

Example~\ref{ex:another} comes after example~\ref{ex:simple}
\end{document}
```

So you have an environment which is basically just a wrapper for a `quote` environment which has its own counter. You can replace quote with something else that adds indentation more to your liking, but the basic idea is there.

If you want it to include the section number as part of the example (e.g. example 1.2) then that's a little more work and maybe something like `amsthm` or `ntheorem` is a better bet...

note that `\refstepcounter` increments the environment's counter, and also makes the environment "visible" to the referencing mechanism.