# Enumitem, resume, reset at section

Tags: sectioning, enumitem

I'm attempting to use `enumitem` to make a list that runs consecutively in a section and then resets.

This question and accepted answer looks promising: [How to use chngcntr with an enumitem newlist with resume?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34494/3929), but it does not quite seem to work when I try it.

The requirement from the author needing it was just that the `Problems` env should be usable several times within the same section, consecutive numbering within the section, and reset at et new section.

Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{xxx}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[xxx]{
    label=\thesection.\arabic*.,
    % no end dot in ref
    ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
    resume=myProblems,
  }
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\section{%
  \restartlist{xxx}%
} 

\newenvironment{Problems}{%
  \paragraph{\textbf{Exercises}}%
  \begin{xxx}}{\end{xxx}}

\begin{document}


\section{test}

\begin{Problems}
  \item A
\end{Problems}

\subsection{subtest}

\begin{Problems}
  \item B
\end{Problems}

\section{test 2}

\begin{Problems}
  \item C
\end{Problems}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The counter resetting (`resume=myProblems`) is stored in macro `\enit@resume@series@myProblems`. Redefining it as empty seems to help:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{xxx}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[xxx]{
    label=\thesection.\arabic*.,
    % no end dot in ref
    ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
    resume=myProblems,
  }
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\section{%
  \let\enit@resume@series@myProblems\@empty
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{Problems}{%
  \paragraph{\textbf{Exercises}}%
  \begin{xxx}}{\end{xxx}}

\begin{document}


\section{test}

\begin{Problems}
  \item A
\end{Problems}

\subsection{subtest}

\begin{Problems}
  \item B
\end{Problems}

\section{test 2}

\begin{Problems}
  \item C
\end{Problems}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Ahh, that was better, the `\restartlist` only sets `\enit@resume@myProblems` to empty. That is not enough in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer `\pretocmd`? In this case it's the same as `\preto` but I think it's better `\pretocmd`.

Comment: @Manuel I have just copied the choice from daleif's code. `\pretocmd` might be more defensive, `\preto` is faster and more efficient.