# Using \Cref of cleveref package in enviroments created with shortcuts

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I'm using the [`cleverref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package. This is how I use it (and it works perfectly):

```
\begin{proposition}[Lalala]\label{lol}
Hahahah
\end{proposition}

It follows directly from \Cref{lol}
```

I'm using the following codes in the preamble:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
```

The enviroment `\begin{prop} ... \end{prop}` works perfectly too. But if I use `\Cref{}` with a proposition created with `\begin{prop}` it does not work. The document shows the symbol "???"

Can I fix this problem? I would like to define enviroments with the corresponding shortcuts like `thm`, `prop`, `defi`, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using cleveref with newenvironment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93856/using-cleveref-with-newenvironment)

Comment: Could you add an MWE (a compilable document showing your problem)?

Comment: @JérômeDequeker and other would-be voters for closure - This posting is *not* a duplicate, since it uses the basic `\newtheorem` mechanism rather than any kind of custom-designed mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two environments (`proposition` and `prop`) that have the same name ("Proposition") and share a common counter, I will assume that they should also be cross-referenced (with `cleveref`'s macros) using the same prefix label, say, "Proposition". This may be accomplished via an instruction such as

```
\crefalias{prop}{proposition}
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm} % if you prefer, use "ntheorem" instead of "amsthm"
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\crefalias{prop}{proposition} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\begin{proposition}[Hahaha]\label{hah}
Hahaha
\end{proposition}

\begin{prop}[Hohoho]\label{hoh}
Hohoho
\end{prop}

\noindent
It follows directly from \Cref{hoh,hah} that \dots
\end{document}
```

This example produces

> It follows directly from Propositions 1.1 and 1.2 that ...

(Observe that the arguments of `\Cref` need not be entered by ascending numerical value; `cleveref` takes care of the sorting by default.)