# Cleverref reference not working in custom environment

Tags: amsmath, environments, cleveref

I have a custom environment defined in a style file, for which I am trying to create a specific cref counter. Here is my environment and the code in `mystyle.sty`

```
\newcounter{exampleCtr}
\setcounter{exampleCtr}{0}

\newenvironment{LogicProgram}{%
    \refstepcounter{exampleCtr}%
    \start@align\tw@\st@rredtrue\m@ne
    \noindent\textbf{Example~\theexampleCtr}
    \hskip\parindent    
}{%
    \endalign   
}
\crefname{exampleCtr}{Example}{Examples}
\Crefname{exampleCtr}{Examples}{Examples}
```

When I try to create a logicprogram, and reference it with cref, I just get "??" (questionmarks) meaning, I suppose, that cref doesn't know what I want to reference to.

```
\begin{LogicProgram}
\label{ex:logic}
& \bot \leftarrow \neg F & : w
\end{LogicProgram}
```

I try to create a reference with `\cref{ex:logic}`, but nothing works. `\Cref` does work very well at other points in my document / work, but I cannot figure out why it cannot find the reference in my `logicprogram` environment.

I have tried [Using cleveref with newenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93856/using-cleveref-with-newenvironment) but this does not work for my environment in my style file. 
What am I doing wrong / how to make this work?

Comment: I have provided a fix below, but this seems to be a very strange way to code mixing text and math mode material. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the fix, that works for now! I have to admit I'm not very familiar with custom environments, and couldn't find a nice environment that allowed the slight indent along with the align — at least, I didn't get anything to work. I then found the idea of this environment definition on this website and changed it only slightly, because it gives the alignment that I wanted exactly. I'm definitely guilty of copying-pasting code here, without good knowledge of what I am doing...

Comment: Is this always a one-line environment, or do you need the multiline capabilities of `align*`?

Comment: Multiline generally, the single line example was just to make it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amsmath` does all sorts of tricks with the labels in its environments.  You need to restore the standard definition which is stored in `\ltx@label` and the syntax here is a little non-standard (as you will discover if you try a simple `\let`):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}

\newcounter{exampleCtr}
\setcounter{exampleCtr}{0}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{LogicProgram}{%
    \refstepcounter{exampleCtr}%
    \start@align\tw@\st@rredtrue\m@ne
    \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\ltx@label{{##1}}}
    \textbf{Example~\theexampleCtr}
    \hskip\parindent
}{%
  \endalign
}
\makeatother

\crefname{exampleCtr}{Example}{Examples}
\Crefname{exampleCtr}{Example}{Examples}

\begin{document}

\begin{LogicProgram}
\label{ex:logic}
& \bot \leftarrow \neg F & : w
\end{LogicProgram}

\Cref{ex:logic}

\end{document}
```

Note you need to include the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair around your code, and `\noindent` has no effect where you used it as you are already in display math, not an ordinary paragraph.