# Referencing tcolorbox environment

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, tcolorbox

I'm trying to make a reference to this environment, but it comes out with the double question mark. Is there anything missing from this environment for me to be able to refer to it?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{testexample}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\exampletext{Eksempel} % If English

 \NewDocumentEnvironment{testexample}{ O{} }
{
\colorlet{colexam}{red!55!black} % Global example color
\newtcolorbox[use counter=testexample]{testexamplebox}{%
% Example Frame Start
empty,% Empty previously set parameters
title={\exampletext\ \thetcbcounter: #1},% use \thetcbcounter to access the 
testexample counter text
% Attaching a box requires an overlay
attach boxed title to top left,
% Ensures proper line breaking in longer titles
minipage boxed title,
% (boxed title style requires an overlay)
boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay= 
{}},
coltitle=colexam,fonttitle=\bfseries, before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt, % Use instead of 
parbox=true. %This ensures parskip is inherited by box.
% Handles box when it exists on one page only
overlay unbroken={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north 
west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
% Handles multipage box: first page
overlay first={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) 
-- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
% Handles multipage box: middle page
overlay middle={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) 
-- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
% Handles multipage box: last page
overlay last={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) - 
- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
}
\begin{testexamplebox}}
{\end{testexamplebox}\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{testexample}[Test]
\label{ex:1}
Here is an example
\end{testexample}

Look at example \ref{ex:1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you turn your snippet into a complete example, including a `tcolorbox` and a reference to it? Edit: that said, you need a label, see section 4.21 in the `tcolorbox` manual.

Comment: Is there **any** reason of putting a `\newtcolorbox` inside a `\NewDocumentCommand`? In any case, the `label=foo` option should work

Comment: I meant `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, but my question remains the same

Comment: I tried to turn the code into a complete snippet, am i doing something wrong with the label?

Comment: @kasp You can use the label key to add so label to a tcolorbox as shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231376/134144

Comment: The code is not compilable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specifications of this box and environment are unclear, but the definition of `examplebox` should be done outside of the environment, as well using the label key.

However, the optional argument of the environment is abused as title of the environment, so saying `label=ex:1` is not possible as an option, since it would be interpreted as a title.

I added a second optional argument with `\NewTColorBox`, the `IfValueTF` option checks for this.

With more information I would recommend a standalone box environment instead of this wrapping.

Off-topic: `ex:1` is a bad label name -- labels with numbers in their name are error prone.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{testexample}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\exampletext{Eksempel} % If English
\NewTColorBox[use counter=testexample]{testexamplebox}{O{}o}{%
% Example Frame Start
empty,% Empty previously set parameters
title={\exampletext\ \thetcbcounter: #1},% use \thetcbcounter to access the 
% Attaching a box requires an overlay
attach boxed title to top left,
% Ensures proper line breaking in longer titles
minipage boxed title,
% (boxed title style requires an overlay)
boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay= 
{}},
coltitle=colexam,fonttitle=\bfseries, before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt, % Use instead of 
parbox=true. %This ensures parskip is inherited by box.
% Handles box when it exists on one page only
overlay unbroken={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north 
west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
% Handles multipage box: first page
overlay first={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) 
-- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
% Handles multipage box: middle page
overlay middle={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) 
-- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
% Handles multipage box: last page
overlay last={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) - 
- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
IfValueTF={#2}{#2}{},
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{testexample}{O{}O{}}
{%
  \colorlet{colexam}{red!55!black} % Global example color
  \begin{testexamplebox}[#1][#2]
}{\end{testexamplebox}\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{testexample}[Test][label=ex:1]
Here is an example
\end{testexample}

Look at example \ref{ex:1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Kasp: You're welcome. Happy TeXing and `tcolorboxing` ;-)

Comment: How would i go about adding a vertical line next to the enviroment like in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21227/example-environment ?