# Highlight environment by setting a violet background color that works on xelatex

Tags: xetex, environments, backgrounds, examples

Please, what I need is an example environment that has a violet [rgb(238, 130, 238) for example] background, the font color black ***and*** this has to work on xelatex (I need this compiler because I'm working with Japanese texts and furigana that only works on xelatex)

Use this sentence on your example:
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
{\fontsize{25}{30}\selectfont 口} meaning mouth
Kun'yomi: くち\
On'yomi: コウ、ク\
\end{example}
\end{document}

Comment: As of 2020, the font will also work in LuaLaTeX, which has fewer color bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can e.g. use tcolorbox.  It will works with xelatex too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{myviolett}{RGB}{238, 130, 238}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=myviolett]
some text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for this comment, especially for this quick answer at this time of the year. This will work, but I expecting something more sophisticated for a book example, like @Jonathan Komar's answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21227/example-environment ... but the package "mdframed" always results in an error on xelatex. I'll use this in my article's texts now! Thank you, hombre!

Comment: @Alex990MW Ulrike is a mujer. :)

Comment: Sorry, perdão, gomenasai! @Ulrike Fischer

Comment: You only asked about violett background and black text, if you want something more sophisticated you should be more specific. Beside this: everything that you can do with mdframed is also possible with tcolorbox (and more, as it is a much more powerful package).

Answer (score 1):

The following works in either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if a character is missing
\usepackage{iftex} % For \ifluatex, \ifxetex
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % For \setmathfont
\usepackage{xcolor, framed} % For shaded*

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common,Scale=1.0,Language=Default]{TeX Gyre Termes} % Clone of Times.
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common,Language=Default]{TeX Gyre Heros} % Clone of Helvetica.
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{Libertinus Mono}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\ifluatex
  \babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{japanese}
\else
  \babelprovide[import]{japanese}
  \usepackage{ucharclasses}
  \setTransitionsForJapanese%
    {\begin{otherlanguage}{japanese}}%
    {\end{otherlanguage}}
\fi

\babelfont[japanese]{rm}
          [Renderer=HarfBuzz]{HaranoAjiMincho}
\babelfont[japanese]{sf}
          [Renderer=HarfBuzz]{HaranoAjiGothic}
% Define \babelfont[japanese]{tt} here, if needed.

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{238, 130, 238}
\newenvironment{example}%
               {\begin{shaded*}}%
               {\end{shaded*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
{\huge 口} meaning mouth Kun'yomi: くち\ On'yomi: コウ、ク\ 
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image: Termes/Hirano Aji Mincho sample]

Here, I used the `framed` package, which should be able to deal with page breaks.  Ulrike Fischer’s solution based on `tcolorbox` will also work, and you can configure that package to do fancier things.